# IBM Connections keeps doing the OAuth dance for gadgets

Tags: oauth-2.0, opensocial, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I've got an embedded experience gadget configured for the IBM Connections activity stream. It seems that the OAuth dance never succeeds, only returning me to the beginning of the OAuth dance (prompt for authorisation).

I see errors like this:

```
[2/25/14 7:17:45:197 EST] 000000c2 BasicOAuth2Me 3   JSONException parsing response
                                 org.apache.commons.json.JSONException: Error occurred during input read.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected character '<' on line 1, column 1
    at org.apache.commons.json.internal.Tokenizer.next(Tokenizer.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.json.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.json.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:85)
    at org.apache.commons.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:128)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:41)
```

...which *may* suggest that XML is returned from *something* instead of JSON.

I'm also seeing `POST /connections/opensocial/gadgets/makeRequest HTTP/1.1`
 returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2014 12:54:12 GMT
Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
X-LConn-Auth: true
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Tue, 25 Feb 2014 12:54:12 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=p.txt
Content-Length: 1029
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US

throw 1; < 'invalid javascript' > {"http://appfusions.demos.ibm.com:2990/jira/rest/api/2/issue/DEMO-12/transitions?expand=transitions.fields":{"rc":200,"body":"","oauthApprovalUrl":"http://appfusions.demos.ibm.com:2990/jira/plugins/servlet/af/oauth/authorize?client_id=8821f0cfd9264c4ed08b00861016886c&realGadgetUri=http%3A%2F%2Fappfusions.demos.ibm.com%3A2990%2Fjira%2Frest%2Fgadgets%2F1.0%2Fg%2Fcom.appfusions.jira.connections.jira-immersive-for-connections%3Aconnections-gadgets%2Fgadgets%2Fjira-ee.xml&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconnectionsww.demos.ibm.com%2Fconnections%2Fopensocial%2Fgadgets%2Foauth2callback&response_type=code&state=WIn_8DLhmOeRc8aIYomi0j2XGIAAd7Ke3j2E4y9SbXpD6aZcmU_sKbJpOh4CEuJKr1NLEEsm8xAB-gzYz9laubsztcW-I-YC8gfq67kGbW2wxYhFh6PCaqEZgAhzD7sfRGsj_bBLykeVpSCRZCI7h8pbO9UbtiBfKDKUDwyqm2t35GWi0DV3KcWZlnKso97-z8Xlzj5AysY5ifWux0nJwHCLJ70Fq4wV738SQ5ZDExqSQkaiGY-w7NlJRHRCVP0wJzIEWP2fsSkNMbN8ui4ULLD1kR0w4T_VlBYS1QXbjvXJ6XUwEc7xhusC2ixvDzhBjjLOmbrwqOdMQnFRrxilX--Q9mI","DataHash":"qgeopmcf02p09qc016cepu22fo"}}
```

Here's a full [trace.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/658119/tmp/trace.log) -- I'm currently logging to trace with these packages:

```
*=info: 
com.ibm.social.pim.resource.*=all: 
com.ibm.lconn.homepage.services.widget.*=all: 
com.ibm.lconn.news.*=all: 
com.ibm.lconn.events.*=all: 
com.ibm.lotus.search.engine.*=all: 
com.ibm.lotus.search.index.*=all: 
com.ibm.lconn.mailin.*=all: 
com.ibm.lotus.connections.core.notify.*=all: 
com.ibm.lconn.scheduler.*=all:
org.apache.shindig.*=all
```

I'd love to know a good way of debugging that `JSONException` as well as more into on the `makeRequest` POST.

Any clues on how to debug further are greatly appreciated.

### Update

I've updated the [trace.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/658119/tmp/trace.log) after Paul's logging suggestion and I'm now seeing exceptions while storing OAuth information:

```
[2/27/14 7:16:17:062 EST] 0000014e RetryConnecti 3   Exception caught during attempt
                                 org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: SqlMapClient operation; SQL [];   
--- The error occurred in resources/news/oauth/OAuth2TokenSQL.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the insert-OAUTH2_TOKEN-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (update failed).  
--- Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column "TBSPACEID=5, TABLEID=14, COLNO=4" is not allowed.. SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, DRIVER=4.13.80; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in resources/news/oauth/OAuth2TokenSQL.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the insert-OAUTH2_TOKEN-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (update failed).  
--- Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column "TBSPACEID=5, TABLEID=14, COLNO=4" is not allowed.. SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, DRIVER=4.13.80
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:228)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:212)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.insert(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:397)
    at com.ibm.lconn.news.data.dao.impl.ibatis.CrudDao.insert(CrudDao.java:394)
    at com.ibm.lconn.news.data.dao.impl.ibatis.oauth.OAuth2TokenDao.insert(OAuth2TokenDao.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
```

The OAuth provider appears to be supplying OAuth tokens correctly from what I can see -- also in  `trace.log`

Comment: you should probably trace these... :com.ibm.ws.security.web.*=all:com.ibm.ws.security.oauth20.*=all:com.ibm.oauth.*=all  then it'll tell more about what's going on with oauth

Comment: Looking at the trace, it seems that your client secret is null:

[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2014-02-25 12:39:46,741 DEBUG [com.appfusions.sobie.utils.OAuthRequestDebug] - <clientSecret: null>

Are you sure you specified your client secret? :)

Comment: Thanks Ben - I had noticed that, but really need a good way of monitoring the requests that IBM Connections makes to external systems. Paul B: Is there a good way of monitoring that by updating the WebSphere trace level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed `tcpflow` on the IBM Connections machine. Tracking the server side OAuth flow on the IBM Connections machine using...

```
root$ tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 2990 | grep -oE '(GET|POST|HEAD) .* HTTP/1.[01]|Host: .*' > cnx-outgoing-2990.log
```

I've found a 404 error on the OAuth provider when IBM Connections POSTs to the access_token URL -- will concentrate on that :)

Comment: what does the system out say? is it a self signed cert for the access_token?  if so, be sure to import it into the trust store for the cell